# Error establishing a database connection after migration to new server

Tags: wordpress

I migrated my wordpress website to another server. Domain didnt change. I copied all wordpres files to new server and imported DB to new server. It is all I did.

I get "Error establishing a database connection" error.

I used below code to check if my DB connection info is correct and it showed it is correct.

```
<?php
$servername   = "localhost";
$database = "database";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
  echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

How can I find the source of the problem?

Comment: Dumb question, but did you edit the wp-config? Are you certain that the details there are the ones you've used in your test script? Did you run the test script from the new server?

Comment: I didn't touch wp-config. All configurations are same with former server. info in the test script and wp-config are same.

Comment: There might be a typo or something missing in DB name/user/pass

Comment: Do you use caching? And did you empty those if you do?

Comment: @BilalNaseer no. Today, I created a new DB user to test it. Same error...

Comment: @bronlund Yes I use. I also suspect from caching so I want to uninstall the plugin. But problem is that, I cannot access to admin panel currently.

Comment: @yavuz did you check in Local host by using XAMPP/WAMP

Comment: I am not using wamp or xampp. I installed LAMP as written here: https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/lamp/how-to-install-a-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-18-04